# Spring AMQP - Recreating deleted queue

Tags: java, spring, spring-amqp

So, I'm using spring amqp with following config:

```
ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
factory.setAutomaticRecoveryEnabled(false);
CachingConnectionFactory ccf = new CachingConnectionFactory(factory);
ccf.setAddresses(addresses);
...
```

And I'm creating my queues manually using amqp admin. All was OK using this code until some of newer library updates:

```
private void recreateContainer() {
    // if we are not already in recreation process
    if (this.recreatingContainer.compareAndSet(false, true)) {
      ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
      executor.execute(
          () -> {
            int attempt = 0;
            while (this.listenerContainer.isRunning() && attempt < MAX_STOP_WAIT_ATTEMPTS) {
              try {
                attempt++;
                Thread.sleep(100);
              } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
              }
            }
            if (attempt == MAX_STOP_WAIT_ATTEMPTS) {
              logger.error("Container took too long to stop");
            }
            logger.info(String.format("Recreating listener container after %s attempts", attempt));
            startNewContainer();
            this.recreatingContainer.set(false);
          });
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void onApplicationEvent(ListenerContainerConsumerFailedEvent event) {
    Object source = event.getSource();
    Assert.isInstanceOf(
        MessageListenerContainer.class,
        source,
        "source must be instance of MessageListenerContainer");
    MessageListenerContainer listenerContainer = (MessageListenerContainer) source;
    // if fatal and this state model is responsible for this listenerContainer
    if (event.isFatal() && this.listenerContainer == listenerContainer) {
      recreateContainer();
    }
  }
```

Then it seems that this got updated from `ListenerContainerConsumerFailedEvent` to `ListenerContainerConsumerTerminatedEvent` and now my code is not working anymore.

If I update exception type, queue gets recreated, but I'm having problem stopping ListenerContainer.

```
ERROR [2021-03-08T16:52:10.291+01:00] lambda$recreateContainer$0: Container took too long to stop
INFO  [2021-03-08T16:52:10.291+01:00] lambda$recreateContainer$0: Recreating listener container after 100 attempts
```

And now instead of 5 listeners, I got 10 (so it seems that listener somehow manages to recover after queue is recreated, but during the state queue is not there - I cannot stop container).

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you post a DEBUG log someplace (like PasteBin or a GitHub Gist) that covers the entire period?

Comment: Still investigating a bit. Since old project with old libs work - there I used `SimpleMessageListenerContainer` and on queue delete it still triggers `ListenerContainerConsumerFailedEvent`. Now I started using `DirectMessageListenerContainer` and it seems on queue delete it triggers `ListenerContainerConsumerTerminatedEvent`. This stopping is possibly not working because of difference in nature between Simple and Direct containers?

Comment: also seems that this is not true anymore `event.isFatal()` on `ListenerContainerConsumerFailedEvent`.

Comment: Maybe you changed behavior now, that on queue delete it will not automatically stop the containers like it was the case before?

Comment: Yes, that seems to be the thing. It will not stop containers automatically on these events. I also noticed that I just need to recreate the queue, and existing containers will just start re-consuming messages from that queue.

Comment: @GaryRussell should I stop container at all in this situation, or is it enough just to recreate the queue manually? It seems container will just pick-it up from there and continue working.

Comment: Yes, there is no need to stop and restart a direct container; it uses a different architecture and can recover from deleted queues and will automatically start consuming again when the queue is re-created.

Comment: Note that even with the `SimpleMessageListenerContainer`, you can `setMissingQueuesFatal=false` and the container will keep trying to recover. By default, it tries 3 times at 5 second intervals, then stopped. When it is false, it will try 3 times at 5 second intervals, then start over again with 3 tries; indefinitely. You can increase the interval if you want to reduce the logging while the queue is missing.

Comment: @GaryRussell is it a bit missleading that `ListenerContainerConsumerTerminatedEvent` is not actually stopping container?

Comment: A container can have multiple consumers (via concurrentConsumers); this event indicates that a consumer terminated, not the whole container; there is no container-level event.

Answer (score 1):

Seems that this code works OK with `DirectMessageListenerContainer`

```
private void recreateContainer() {
    // if we are not already in recreation process
    if (this.recreatingContainer.compareAndSet(false, true)) {
      this.listenerContainer.stop();
      ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
      executor.execute(
          () -> {
            int attempt = 0;
            while (this.listenerContainer.isRunning() && attempt < MAX_STOP_WAIT_ATTEMPTS) {
              try {
                attempt++;
                Thread.sleep(100);
              } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
              }
            }
            if (attempt == MAX_STOP_WAIT_ATTEMPTS) {
              log.error("Container took too long to stop");
            }
            log.info(String.format("Recreating listener container after %s attempts", attempt));
            startNewContainer();
            this.recreatingContainer.set(false);
          });
    }
  }

  @Override
  public void onApplicationEvent(ListenerContainerConsumerTerminatedEvent event) {
    Object source = event.getSource();
    Assert.isInstanceOf(
        MessageListenerContainer.class,
        source,
        "source must be instance of MessageListenerContainer");
    MessageListenerContainer sourceContainer = (MessageListenerContainer) source;
    // if this state model is responsible for this listenerContainer
    if (this.listenerContainer == sourceContainer) {
      recreateContainer();
    }
  }
```

So, I had to use `ListenerContainerConsumerTerminatedEvent`, remove check `event.isFatal` and manually stop container on recreation `this.listenerContainer.stop();`.